# When the same monitoring item is used in the Zabbix trigger, the values of item.value1 and item.value2 in the custom alarm message are always the same

Tags: zabbix

I want to monitor changes in IP, and this is my trigger expression:

```
    
last(/Zabbix server/check.ip[www.a.com])<>last(/Zabbix server/check.ip[www.a.com],#2)
```

I want to reflect the changes in new and old IPs，so my custom alert message is like this:

```
TITLE：{EVENT.NAME}  
IP CHANGE：{ITEM.VALUE2} ==> {ITEM.VALUE1}  
EVENT TIME：{EVENT.DATE} {EVENT.TIME}  
EVENT ID：{EVENT.ID}
```

But I found that {ITEM. VALUE1} and {ITEM. VALUE2} always get the same value, which is the latest value of the monitored item。
Does {ITEM.VALUE<1-9>} always get the same last value when using the same items in the trigger expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Zabbix 6.4, yes.

> the historical (**at-the-time-of-event**) value of the Nth item in the trigger expression

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/6.4/en/manual/appendix/macros/supported_by_location#items